# How to remove file on android using ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to remove a file on my android using a single ADB command.

I understand you can just do adb shell and then remove the file using rm.

But I need it to be a one line execution.

I’ve tried:

```
adb rm-f /directory/file.txt

adb shell rm-f /directory/file.txt
```

Both **don’t delete** the file I want.

Comment: first type command `adb shell` then press enter and then next commands `rm -f /sdcard/test.txt`

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki thanks for your reply, but in my question I’m looking for a one line execution. Because in the end I’m going to need to execute the command through python.

Comment: We can do it in single command line using   adb shell rm -r sdcard/filename.txt

Comment: you are not applying space between rm and -f see `adb shell rm-f /directory/file.txt` try with `adb shell rm -f /directory/file.txt`

Answer (score 19):

Delete file on android:

```
adb shell rm sdcard/download/file.ext
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with directories

Answer (score 3):

I noticed in your comments you are looking for one line execution since you're gonna be using Python. Well as an alternative you could use the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to write to stdout allowing you to execute as many commands of choice

for example

```py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen([r'adb', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=
subprocess.PIPE) #start adb
process.stdin.write('shell \n') # Parse in input into the program
process.stdin.write('rm *\n') # Parse in second input
line=process.stdout.readline() # Read a line from stdout
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me to run the following command:

adb shell rm -f -rR -v /sdcard/Documents/