# How to delete a directory content using ADB commands

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to delete a directory content of an Android device using the following command:

adb shell rm -f /data/vendor/aplogd

BUt i got the following message and the contect is not deleted:

rm: /data/vendor/aplogd: Is a directory

is this a syntax error?

Comment: Your question is of no future use to our readership. Your issue is simply that you have made not attempt to read and understand the help and usage information for the single command you have chosen to use. Please self-delete your off topic question, in order that it does not attact down-voting.

Comment: @Compo, I disagree with this being off topic. Why the question about [how to delete files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283773/how-to-remove-file-on-android-using-adb) is acceptable and this one is not? As a non linux user, I would expect `rm` to remove whatever is in that path, being a file or a folder... this question definitely helped me understand `rm` better and the answer did solve my issue.

Comment: @GuilhermeTaffarelBergamin, differing opinions are fully expected. BTW, this is not a forum, the comment section is not for chatting!

Answer (score 4):

To delete a directory with the rm command you have to use the -r option:

> adb shell rm -r /data/vendor/aplogd

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to do it together with "su" yet in a batch file? I tried adb shell "su -c rm -r -f THE_PATH" but it didn't work as it complains about the "-r".

Comment: No sorry, I would assume it works the same as the normal command.

Comment: It does. Just need to add something :  `adb shell "su -c 'rm -r -f PATH_TO_FOLDER'"`